# How to set array value in in dropdown value in anjularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanted to pass array value in dropdown(select) value but it always shows array key in dropdown value.

I am trying code given below

```
$databases = array(
    'db1','db2','db3','db4','db5',
    );
```

**Angular Code**

```
<select ng-model="databases" ng-change="showTables($index)" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in databases" >
<option value="">-- choose Database --</option>
```

Comment: show ur angular code

Answer (score 0):

`ng-options` is build like this :

```
ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in databases"
```

After the `in`, you have your list. Between `for` and `in`, it's the object that you will use for a single `select`.

Then you have 2 other attributes. Here it's key and value. Value is what you want to print in your list, what is visible for the user. Key is the data which will be put in your DOM as "value".

Here is you want to set your array attribute in your value. Because here you have a simple data, and you don't need any difference between what is visible in your list, and what is in your DOM value, you can do this :

```
ng-options="value for value in databases"
```

Moreover, I also notice that you use your variable `databases` on your `ng-model`. That's not a good idea, this will erase your list when you will select a value. You have to use an other var.

Answer (score 0):

If the array contains only `String`s, you can simply use ng-repeat:

**Html**:

```
<div ng-controller="DatabaseSelectExampleController as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.selectedDatabase">
        <option ng-repeat="actDatabase in vm.databases" value="{{actDatabase}}">
            {{actDatabase}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
    .controller('DatabaseSelectExampleController', function(){
        this.databases = ['database one', 'someother db', 'a db aswell'];
        this.selectedDatabase = this.databases[0];
    });
```